# How does the concatAll operator from RXJS determine if the previous inner observable has completed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

### Goal

I am trying to understand how the [`concatAll()` operator from RXJS works](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatAll), and when exactly it determines an inner RXJS `Observable` is completed.

### Current Understanding

From how I interpreted the `concatAll()` documentation, `concatAll()` will **not** subscribe to the next observable emitted to the source *until* the previous observable emitted to said source has completed.

However, while putting together a local demonstration to test my understanding of the operator, I received an unexpected result.

### A Demo of My Problem

My demonstration features two "widgets":

- A calendar widget ()
- A chat widget ()

First, the "application" starts by publishing a `LOGIN` event to tell the widgets to initialize. Next, the calendar widget processes the `LOGIN` event and publishes a `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` event.

However, at this point, I was expecting `concatAll()` piped onto the `source` RXJS `Subject` to prevent the `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` from reaching the Chat Widget. I figured that since the Observable associated with the `LOGIN` event has not completed, `concatAll()` would wait to emit the `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` event to subscribers until it was complete.

Below is the code to my demo, and here is a link to its associated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kzpxzi-zsqznz?file=index.ts

```typescript
import { concatAll, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const source = new Subject<Observable<string>>();
const eventBus = source.pipe(concatAll());

const publish = (event) => {
  source.next(
    new Observable((subscriber) => {
      subscriber.next(event);
      subscriber.complete();
    })
  );
};

// Calendar Widget
eventBus.subscribe({
  next: (event) => {
    if (event === 'LOGIN') {
      console.log(' Calendar initializing...');
      publish('CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS');
    }
  },
});

// Chat Widget
eventBus.subscribe({
  next: (event) => {
    if (event === 'LOGIN') {
      console.log(' Chat initializing...');
    }

    if (event === 'CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS') {
      console.log(' Chat opening birthday prompt');
    }
  },
});

// LOGIN event
publish('LOGIN');
```

If you check your logs you'll see the following:

```
 Calendar initializing...
 Chat opening birthday prompt
 Chat initializing...
```

### The Problem

In my demo, I was expecting the logs to output the following:

```
 Calendar initializing...
 Chat initializing...
 Chat opening birthday prompt
```

This is where my understanding of `concatAll()` is falling apart. Here is how I was thinking that `concatAll()` and my code would execute together:

1. `publish` is called with the `LOGIN` event
2. An RXJS `Observable` is emitted to the `source` RXJS `Subject`, which will subsequently emit a `LOGIN` string whenever this observable is subscribed to
3. `concatAll()` checks to see if there are any incomplete Observable values emitted to `source`
4. Because there are no incomplete observables on `source`, `concatAll()` subscribes to the observable in step 2
5. `concatAll()` "pulls" the emitted value out of the inner observable, i.e., `"LOGIN"`
6. `concatAll()` emits the `LOGIN` event to subscribers of eventBus
7. The calendar widget () processes the `LOGIN` event
8. The calendar widget () logs "initializing..."
9. The calendar widget () calls `publish` with a `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` event
10. An RXJS `Observable` is emitted to the `source` RXJS `Subject`, which will subsequently emit a `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` string whenever this observable is subscribed to
11. `concatAll()` checks to see if there are any incomplete Observable values emitted to `_eventBus`

At this point, though, I was expecting step 12 to be the following:

12. Because there are incomplete observables (i.e. the one emitted to `source` in step 2), `concatAll()` **does not** subscribe to the observable

Instead, however, the `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` event *was* emitted to subscribers, hence the " Chat opening birthday prompt" log right after the  `Calendar initializing...` log.

I am not sure how the `CALENDAR_HAS_BIRTHDAYS` event was emitted. Although the `LOGIN` event did result in a subscriber publishing another event, I figured that RXJS would have known at this point that the `Observable` associated with the `LOGIN` was not completed.

What is it about my understanding of RXJS (and possibly the relationship with the JavaScript call stack) that is leaving me confused about the sequence of logs in my demonstration?

Comment: RxJS is open-source. You can find the answer here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/packages/rxjs/src/internal/operators/concatAll.ts

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Here's what's going on: You might think of rxjs as plumbing, setting up pipes so that information streams through and come out the other end however you like, but it's better to think of rxjs as plumbing plans or instructions, entrusting the rxjs code library to make the pipes as specified on demand (i.e. when subscribed to).

If you look at it that way, it makes more sense because you are subscribing twice, so when `source` emits a string, the `concatAll` operator runs once *per subscriber!*

The way to fix this is to replace `source.pipe(concatAll())` with `source.pipe(concatAll(), share())`

When you use [`share`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/share) or [`shareReplay`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/shareReplay) then everything upstream will be completed once¹ no matter how many times it's subscribed to downstream.

---

¹ "Once" has the following exceptions:

1. If never subscribed to, then it's never computed at all!
2. `share` does it's stuff when the number of subscribers changes from 0 to any. If all subscriptions end, then it's subscribed to again, `share` restarts again so the upstream operations will be computed.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `share`. The theory behind `share` makes a lot of sense, especially for what I'm trying to achieve. In fact, now that I know about `share`, I could even remove the higher order observable and solve this a different way without needing `concatAll`.

However, at this point, for the sake of my understanding, I'm still not entirely sure why two subscriptions affect the behavior of `concatAll` in my demonstration. When `concatAll` runs for both subscriptions, wouldn't each "run" see that there is an incomplete `Observable`?

Comment: Nope, each run would exhaust one then move on to the next Observable.

Comment: I can see why you expected it to go "across then down" but, since you aren't `share`ing it's computing "down then across"